# copy from file and paste in the terminal without x server

Tags: bash, terminal, console

I have got an Ubuntu Linux without x server installed on it (because it's only a gateway). I am requested by an application (ossec,-my question is not ossec related-) to paste information into the terminal. I have got the info in a file in ~/. the information to paste is:

```
[SECRET KEY IN BASE64 REDACTED]
```

I do not know how to paste it.

Here is what I have got:

```
*****************************************
* OSSEC HIDS v2.8 Agent manager.        *
* The following options are available:  *
*****************************************

 (I)mport key from the server (I).
 (Q)uit.
Choose your action: I or Q: I

*Provide the key generated by the server.
* The best approach is to cut and paste it. 
*** OBS: do not include spaces or new lines. 

Paste it here (or '\q' to quit):
```

thank you folks!

Comment: Since you revealed it to the entire internet, you need to destroy and re-create that key now (unless it's a *public* key, but it sounds like it isn't).

Comment: even though it's redacted, the key is available to anyone by looking at the edit history of the question. You should follow @zwol's advice.

Comment: @drs I flagged the question (and the answer below that repeated the key) for a moderator to maybe lock out access to the edit history.  Shoulda done that hours ago, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`gpm`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/gpm). You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install gpm
```

Once that is finished, you will have a working mouse. Now you can `cat` the file that contains your data, select it and then paste it with the middle mouse button.

Assuming, of course, that you have a mouse.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like redirecting standard input may work for you.  Try creating a file (named 'myinput') with two lines:

```
I
(the key goes here)
```

and run your command again like this:

```
cmd < myinput
```

The less-than sign above will send the contents of 'myfile' to your command as if it was typed on the keyboard.

If your command is actually a shell script you may also be able to dissect it and figure out how to submit your key directly to the underlying program.

Comment: The first line answers the first question "import or quit", the second supplies the key.  Both lines should end with newline characters.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had missed that the program read input twice. I saw and deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on how `screen` or `tmux` do cut'n'paste. Both mimic cut'n'paste using cursor keys and some other command keys, so this will work wherever you can start `screen` or `tmux`. No real mouse is needed, will work via `ssh` too...

Or...

If you have physical access to that server's text console and a mouse is attached, read about `gpm` which will give you a mouse for the text consoles which can do cut'n'paste as usual.

In this context `screen` or `tmux` will work too. It's never a mistake to know at least one of them...